# Props, state, and effects are giving me trouble when fetching API data and passing to child component using IF ELSE logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

When I search the term 'react' using my SearchBooks.js component, the provided API array will log to console and update as I type (correct). I want to render either SearchError.js or DisplayOnShelf.js using IF ELSE logic based on if this array has 1 or more results. So far, it never renders the component (DisplayOnShelf.js) or pass on the data. I feel like it's something to do with the query state and effects hook. Please note, only certain search terms work. "React" is one of them.

https://github.com/gthmpsn1/book-tracking.git

Comment: Please include relevant code in the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a numerical operation on the array itself, rather than the `length` of the array.

Instead of

```
{searchInventory > 0
                    ? <DisplayOnShelf bookInventory={searchInventory} shelfInfo={shelfInfo} />
                    : null
                }
```

You need

```
{searchInventory.length > 0
                    ? <DisplayOnShelf bookInventory={searchInventory} shelfInfo={shelfInfo} />
                    : null
                }
```

The former doesnt work since an array is in and of itself not a number, so your condition always evaluates to false which would explain why it never renders/runs the `DisplayOnShelf` component. So you need to access the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property which I think was your original intention.